# SQL Anywhere Remote server connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sybase, sqlanywhere, sybase-asa

I'm trying to link tables from MS SQL Server(on Windows) to SQL Anywhere(on Linux)

Have installed SQL Server driver: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#ubuntu17

Have tested connection to SQL Server with sqlcmd.

In SQL Anywhere I have made a Remote Server with this query:

```
CREATE SERVER "lnkIS" CLASS 'MSSODBC' USING 'host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;port=nnnn;driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.5.so.2.1;uid=wis;pwd=xxx;eng=WisData';
```

But when I test the connection I get:

```
Connection failed.
Unable to connect to server 'lnkIS': [Sybase][ODBC Driver Manager] Unable to load driver /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.5.so.2.1
[Sybase][ODBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Unable to connect to server 'lnkIS': [Sybase][ODBC Driver Manager] Unable to load driver /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.5.so.2.1
SQLCODE: -656
SQLSTATE: HY000
SQL Statement: SELECT FIRST table_name FROM dbo.sp_remote_tables( 'lnkIS', NULL, NULL, NULL, 1 ) ORDER BY 1
```

I have not found any examples on how to use a driver other than Sybase.
Anyone had any luck with proxytables against SQL Server?

Comment: Isn't `1.1.1.1` the DNS resolver for Cloudflare?

Comment: changed 1.1.1.1 to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Comment: Got this answer from SAP Support.
https://wis.no/filer/SAP_KB2917411.pdf

And it is looking promising, but we have Ubuntu and a different version of SQL Anywhere.
But it might help someone.

Will update if we get a KB that fixes our problem.